# Where do i find nameservers of my Heroku App?

Tags: heroku, dns, nameservers

This can be done thru Zerigo. But can't i find the nameservers myself from somewhere and update it at the accound where i purchased my domain from ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Heroku doesn't provide DNS services therefore there are no name servers.

You use your domain name registrars control panel to point your DNS records at your Heroku application. Typically this is a CNAME record pointing at the .herokuapp.com entry. So www.mydomain.com would be a CNAME to myapp.herokuapp.com.

Comment: This critical piece of information should be clearly stated in their official documentation, but it isn't. I spent a few days of pure frustration only to find out that I wasn't supposed to edit the nameserver in my google domains account. Thanks John Beynon!

Comment: Is this answer still accurate? I see on my Heroku app's settings: "You can add custom domains to any Heroku app, then visit Configuring DNS to setup your DNS target.:

Answer (score 13):

My Domain Name Manager (Brinkster) required name servers, and did not support CNAME records. So I needed to do the following:

1. Install the Zerigo DNS add-on for my Heroku app.
2. Add the domain name in the Settings tab of my Heroku app.
3. In the Resources tab of my Heroku app. click "Zerigo DNS" under "Add-ons".
4. In the Zerigo management console, click the "Nameservers" tab.
5. Copy the name servers into the form in Brinkster's Domain Manager control panel.
   [image: Brinkster Domain Manager]

Comment: Someone posted a comment here saying that Zerigo was US only.  However, I investigated this a little bit, and I believe it is worldwide.  Here are there docs on the topic: https://www.zerigo.com/managed-dns/global-network
Also, I ran www.webpagetest.org tests from Moscow and Paris, and they were able to access my site.

If you don't like Zerigo, the other alternative appears to be Point DNS.

Comment: It's shut down now.

Comment: What is currently available, I joined the party late.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but this is still a problem with wanting to use the Heroku app for the root domain.

I migrated my DNS settings to CloudFlare, as they offer to point the root domain (example.com) as well as aliases ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) to a CNAME. This allows one to use the Heroku app as the root domain without running into the headache of having to point the root domain to an IP address. You can then install an SSL certificate for the root domain and (typically) the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) alias as well.