# How I can park heroku domain instead of pointing? My domain has no cname option

Tags: django, heroku, dns, subdomain, cname

I am a newbie to Heroku. I have purchased a domain which only supports nameservers and not CNAME. But I can not find nameservers in Heroku. So is there any way to use that domain in Heroku? It has a .pk extension. Anybody guide me, please. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do i find nameservers of my Heroku App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586017/where-do-i-find-nameservers-of-my-heroku-app)

Comment: You can use addon called poindns

Answer (score 0):

1. Add new add POINTDNS
2. Add your domian to settings section
3. When you click on POINDNS it will show you 3 NS
4. Update your NS in domain name registrar